# ASPxClientComboBox AddItem method throws an error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

When calling `ASPxClientComboBox.AddItem()` I get an error in the `_aspxRemoveAttribute` function, that obj is null.

I've traced it to the `CreateNewItem` function, which never returns a result.

My combo box starts unpopulated, and I'm trying to add items on the client side, but I got the same error when trying to add items to a combo box with items already added from the server side.

This is using the v2011 vol 2.5 release.

**EDIT**
Here is the combo box markup:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="95%" data-bind="dxDataBind: Countries, keyMember: 'Id', displayMember: 'Name', SelectedKey: CountryId">
    <ValidationSettings>
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Country required" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

The data-bind attribute is part of KnockoutJS, which I am attempting to adapt to bind to other controls.

Essentially at the moment I'm just trying to add an item to an empty combo box on the client side, with two string parameters.

Comment: would you share your markup? is there any item in ASPxComboBox initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the **ASPxComboBox.ClientInstanceName** property to enable the control’s [client-side programmatic object](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4223) and use the client-side [AddItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBox_AddItemtopic) method as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="95%" ClientInstanceName="cmb">
    <ValidationSettings>
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Country required" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="OnClick();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClick() {
        var text="Text1";
        var value="Value1";

        cmb.AddItem(text, value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I was doing the AddItem correctly etc, I hadn't specified the ClientInstanceName property though.  However the docs say that the api will be enabled through setting EnableClientSideApi, or ClientInstanceName being set.  I set neither and yet I was still able to use the client api, it just didn't work correctly.

Comment: >>*I set neither and yet I was still able to use the client api, it just didn't work correctly.* How do you call this code

Comment: It's a little complicated, but basically I am searching the declared variables in the page, looking for instances of DevExpress controls, and then finding their matching html elements.  I'm using `x instanceof ASPXClientComboBox` to test the variables, so it's finding an instance.  I admit it's not likely for most people to call the code this way.  I don't even know what the instance name was on the client side as this all happens automatically. (In case you're wondering, I'm writing a binding for KnockoutJS to allow that to work with devexpress controls - it's looking really good!)

Answer (score 1):

Embarassingly I worked out this was due to EnableClientSideScript not being enabled.  However the client side api was available, it just did not function correctly, which doesn't seem like the correct behaviour.